# Need expert's comment on deciding DB storage or file base

Tags: c#, multithreading, database-design, hard-drive

Hi Friends
I have an application that stores thousands of text files in database with average of 3KB each.
and another table storing brief info about them that searched more frequently.
with 140,000 records, my database performance get too slow.

I thought that i could store those files on disk that reduce my database size about 80%. these files are stored only for the purpose of display (reading file content and display) but not for any database operation on them. but my website has about 1000 users and I'm afraid if i store those files on disk, it gets worst (disk I/O operation increase, reading files in different session could increase I/O moving hard disk head back and forward plus I can't control reading files in one thread only)

any guys has related experience ?
Please make this decision for me.
THANKS THANKS

Comment: What is your current database setup? Is this running on a server, a workstation, or a "normal" computer?

Comment: You need to optimize your DB. 140K records is not that much.

Comment: You might want to profile your production application first to see if it is really the database, network latency or the application that is connecting to it.

Comment: Are these files common files being used? Cache to improve performance can be another good option.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 on windows server 2008, I have no more than two table describes so what kind of optimizing you think, Yes it is absolutely the database cause in early days it runs smoothly but now it gets slow plus its memory usage is high, i think normal caching couldn't help in this case or maybe you have some new caching strategy in mind !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take your comment `Please make this decision for me. THANKS THANKS` literally.

- Install at least 8 gig of memory in
  the db server (better SQL cache)

  Configure two disks as a mirror and
  place the log file for your
  application db on the mirror.  Do not
  compress this disk (faster log file writes)

  Configure 4 disks as a Raid 10 and
  place the db on the Raid 10.  Do not
  compress this disk (better read performance than raid 5)

  Configure a single disk as the
  location of the tempDB.  Do not
  compress this disk (isolate activity of tempDB)

  Run only SQL Server on the server.

  Ensure your db has the correct
  indexes by inspecting the missing
  index dynamic management view.

  Ensure your db has a maintenance plan
  to reduce db and index fragmentation

  Extract and reload each of the “text”
  files from the database.  Prior to
  loading the text file compress (zip)
  the file with the tool of your
  choice.  Store the “text” file in a
  varbinary datatype.  Configure the
  application to uncompress the file
  prior to display (reduce disk IO for SQL to store 'text' and network io to client)

  Benchmark you application with a
  known number of users and searches

  Compare your benchmark with actual
  values during client usage

  Monitor disk wait, network IO and
  memory on a regular bases.

If you still have poor performance contract a SQL DBA to evaluate your system.  I believe performanceDBA on this site is in the contract business.

Answer (score 2):

With out much more info I would suggest that you look more deeply into where the performance problem stems from. Are your queries efficient, are there indexes to support your queries.

With regard to storing the files in the database, well that is interesting. I can only give my personal opinion on that which is as a rule I would rather store the files on disk and just store the reference to the file ie. path in the database. But there are many pros/cons to consider here, one thing is that your backups will need to span more than just the database backup.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I'm here for that. I'm agree with you but I'm afraid of heavy disk IO (backup is not my main concern, now). do you have any real experience on this ?

Comment: I'm using Lucene for searching and from it's result I'm query against database (on PK field) to fetch the record. no indexing, nor complex query involved. my Lucene engine searches in smaller than 80ms but results fetched slowly

Comment: @Ehsan, I have no experiance with Lucene, but I have experience with storing large amounts of documents which are referenced from the database. In my case the documents are large documents and are kept on dedicated storage outside of the database with no problems.